# How to fixed footer into bottom of last page only

Tags: html, css, reactjs, printing

I'm try to set position of footer to bottom of last page only with `window.print()` but not working. My printing document are multiple page.

1. used `postion: fixed` it's working but footer display all pages.
2. `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`  not working.
   Result : [open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgFct.png)

Expected results: [open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MysfT.png)

HTML:

```html
<div className="header">
  Header Content
</div>

<table className='table'>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>

<div className='summarize'>
  ...
</div>

<div className='footer'>
  Footer Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
@media print {
  html,
  body {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  @page {
    size: A4;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1;
  }
  
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 320px;
    top: 0mm;
  }
  
  .footer {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: need some code my guy

Comment: what kind of behavior are you expecting? Do you want the footer to stick to the bottom and the table data to go behind the footer? https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-cache-iszt3?file=/src/App.js